# Mobile devices wont get View.Mobile.cshtml views after visiting page with desktop

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I created a asp.net mvc app with a `Index.cshtml` and a `Index.Mobile.cshtml`. The views are using the same controller and action. In development I get the mobile view on my phone and with desktop the desktop view. Everything works as expected.

After deploying the application to the production server everything works as expected on a smartphone, until I navigate from a desktop browser to the page. After I navigated from a desktop browser to the page I won't get the mobile view anymore on a mobile device.

I disabled and enabled cache settings but get either way i have this strange behavior. Am i missing something?

edited:

I got the following theme structure:

/Themes/DefaultTheme/Views/Cart/Index.Mobile.cshtml
/Themes/OceanasTheme/Views/Cart/Index.cshtml

In my custom razor view engine I modified the ViewLocationFormats, simplified:

```
var customViewLocationFormats = new List<string>();
customViewLocationFormats.Add("~/Themes/DefaultTheme/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml");
customViewLocationFormats.Add("~/Themes/OceanasTheme/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml");

//override default view location
ViewLocationFormats = customViewLocationFormats.ToArray();
```

When I copy the `Index.Mobile.cshtml` to the OceanasTheme folder the same problem appears, except I get the `Mobile.сshtml` from the OceanasTheme each time after I visited with desktop. (the desktop gets the `Index.cshtml` from the OceanasTheme).

Updated to MVC 5.2.7 and removed Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes package. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: pls share your code for more details

Comment: How did you turn-off the caching? Are you using [OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RazorViewEngine is caching views with DefaultViewLocationCache. The .Mobile view location is stored in cache after first request with mobile. When requesting with a desktop browser the desktop variant is not found in the cache, so RazorViewEngine is gonna try to find the view on the disk. It will find the view in the different folder, and will store it in cache, But it also checks if the mobile exists in that folder. Because the .Mobile is not in this folder it will overwrite the cache with an empty path.

I fixed this issue by creating a custom implementation of IViewLocationCache.

Comment: Can you share a bit of your code which uses your implementation of this please? It would be greatly helpful to anyone who's running into the same issue.

Comment: See for reference: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/DefaultViewLocationCache.cs

I just created a additional check before setting the cache in the InsertViewLocation method.